# Slide frame offset inside a strip

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I have several small strip of different video who match beats of background music.
Later I have the same sequence of beats so I want to reuse my strips but with a slight difference of offset for each strip.

The issue is than the only way I see to do that is to pick each strip, grab the end until I found the sequence I want then pick the start to shrink it again to the right time. This is really not handy and time consuming (knowing that the media is about 10 minutes and the seq I want is 10 frames long)

Is there a way to "slide" the frames inside a strip ?

Comment: Just hit S to slide strips.

Comment: woo, can't believe I did'nt see this one. You can post it as answer, thats exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just hit <kbd>S</kbd> to slide Strips in place.